# How to verify password exists using client_side_validations gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I have a change password form that requires a user to provide their current password. Using the client_side_validations gem, is it possible to verify that the current password is correct using a remote validator/javascript? If so, how?

**app/views/passwords/new.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @password_form, url: passwords_path, method: :post, validate: true do |f|
  = f.input :original_password
  = f.input :new_password
  = f.input :new_password_confirmation, required: true
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

**app/forms/password_form.rb**

```
  ...

  attr_accessor :original_password, :new_password
  validate :verify_original_password
  validates_presence_of :original_password, :new_password
  validates_confirmation_of :new_password
  validates :new_password, password: true

  def verify_original_password
    unless @user.authenticate(original_password)
      errors.add :original_password, "is not correct"
    end
  end

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't validate password correctness client-side without passing the client an enormous list of all the (presumably) hashed passwords in your DB. This is computationally not really feasible, but even worse you would be exposing a list of all your users' hashed passwords! It wouldn't be hard for a hacker to break open at least a few of these (I've heard stories of people decrypting >80% of a list of MD5 hashed passwords in <1 hour).

So you'll have to speak to the server to verify a password.

Comment: I understand passwords can't be verified on the client-side as you describe. I am referring to the client_side_validations gem, which apparently you can use a [remote validator/javascript](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations#remote-validators) to check existence -- I just don't know how to check password existence for a given user. Sorry if my question wasn't very clear.